# Does range() not evaluate its argument every time?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

`l` is passed as an argument to `range` function whose value is modified inside `for` loop, but the loop is going for `10` times instead of `5`.

```
i = 0
l = 10
for i in range(l):
    print i,l
    l = l-1
```

The output is

```
0 10
1 9
2 8
3 7
4 6
5 5
6 4
7 3
8 2
9 1
```

While I expected

```
0 10
1 9
2 8
3 7
4 6
```

Does `range()` evaluates value for the first time only or something else is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the `for` loop evaluates the iterable expression just once.

`range()` is called *once*, and the `for` loop then iterates over the result.

Quoting from the [`for` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> The expression list is **evaluated once**; it should yield an iterable object.

emphasis mine.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not how often `range` evaluates its argument, but how often `for item in sequence` evaluates `sequence`.  The answer is once.  When you write `for i in range(l)`, `range(l)` is evaluated once and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

range(l) is evaluated once, what is being updated is the value of l in the print statement.